# How to PHP get bit depth of a given PNG image file?

Tags: php, png, bit-depth

In PHP code, given an .png image path, I need to detect the bit-depth of that image. How can I do that?

I've tried to use getImageSize() and read the `bits` as below sample code but it always returns '8' for 24-bits/32-bits image.

Please help.

```
class Utils {
    //Ham de lay bits cua image
    public static function getBits($image) {
        $info = getImageSize($image);
        return $info['bits'];
    }
}
```

Comment: my guess it means 8bits per channel.

Comment: @cweiske I'm sorry about my 68% rate - I've got lot's of questions remained unanswerred. Can you help?

Comment: @hakre I always pick the most correct answer to be the accepted one. I just need you understand that 32% of my questions remain incorrect answered and I leave them unaccepted - NOT because I am a careless man :). Thank you for your remind on that anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PNG Images are not that supported for *channels* and *bits* by [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php). However you can use a little function to obtain these values: [`get_png_imageinfo()`](https://github.com/ktomk/Miscellaneous/tree/master/get_png_imageinfo):

```
$file = 'Klee_-_Angelus_Novus.png';
$info = get_png_imageinfo($file);
print_r($info);
```

Gives you for the example picture:

```
Array
(
    [bit-depth] => 4
    [bits] => 4
    [channels] => 1
    [color] => 3
    [color-type] => Indexed-colour
    [compression] => 0
    [filter] => 0
    [height] => 185
    [interface] => 0
    [width] => 291
)
```

It returns the channels and bits as well like some would expect them from [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) next to some more information specific to the PNG format. The meaning of the values next to bits and channels are [documented in the PNG specification](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/iso/index-object.html#11IHDR).

Comment: `get_png_imageinfo` seems broken with PHP 5.5 (works perfect with 5.4). It fails at the `array_shift` comparison. Potentially something new within `unpack()`.

Comment: With php 5.5+, replacing `A8sig` with `a8sig` (or equivalently, `Z8sig`) on line 22 does it. According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php, `a` and `Z` refers to a NUL-padded string, while `A` refers to a SPACE-padded string.

Answer (score 7):

From the [getImageSize documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php):

> bits is the number of bits for each color.

So 8 bits is correct, because if there's three channels (RGB) with eight bits each, you end up with a total of 24 bits. An additional alpha channel gives you another eight bits, totalling 32.

Try returning this:

```
return $info['channels'] * $info['bits'];
```

This doesn't work for every kind of image type, however. Read the documentation for how gifs and jpegs work.

Comment: Yeah. It doesn't work for PNG image. So PHP cannot deal with PNG bit-depth issues, can it? I really feel weird since PHP is growing rapidly